# Boolean DataFrame from Series with itself in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with category information stored in a column, like this (there are only 2 categories, but many items):

```
| index | item      | category |
|-------|-----------|----------|
| 0     | water     | drink    |
| 1     | pasta     | food     |
| 2     | burger    | food     |
| 3     | pepsi     | drink    |
| 4     | chocolate | food     |
```

I want to create a mask DataFrame, but instead of using category names, I would like to have each item as both a row and a column. Entries will be 1 for items in the same category, 0 otherwise:

```
| item      | water | pasta | burger | pepsi | chocolate |
|-----------|-------|-------|--------|-------|-----------|
| water     | 1     | 0     | 0      | 1     | 0         |
| pasta     | 0     | 1     | 1      | 0     | 1         |
| burger    | 0     | 1     | 1      | 0     | 1         |
| pepsi     | 1     | 0     | 0      | 1     | 0         |
| chocolate | 0     | 1     | 1      | 0     | 1         |
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this in Pandas? I couldn't figure out if there was a quick way to go about it, since in all the documentation examples I could find, boolean masks use the category names as column headers (rather than having the items themselves as both columns and rows).

Comment: @user3483203 So I could call get_dummies, which would make a table with the 2 categories as columns. Then do a.multiply(a.T) + b.multiply(b.T), which I believe would work. However that seems like a lot of steps (maybe not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was incorrect in my comment, this required some pre-processing

First, **`merge`** on category:

```
df1 = df.merge(df, on='category')
```

**`pd.crosstab`**

```
pd.crosstab(df1.item_x, df1.item_y)

item_y     burger  chocolate  pasta  pepsi  water
item_x
burger          1          1      1      0      0
chocolate       1          1      1      0      0
pasta           1          1      1      0      0
pepsi           0          0      0      1      1
water           0          0      0      1      1
```

Comment: Thanks, I was sure there was a way to use some combination of reshaping methods but I couldn't figure out the right one. This works great :)